# Get values from table of text fields javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form which actually is a table of text fields. The html looks like this:

```
<form>
  <table id="table">
            <tr>
              <th>Player</th>
              <th>Number</th>
              <th>Con.per.day</th>
              <th>P.100.kg</th>
              <th>P.day</th>
              <th>I.month</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td>Result</td>
             </tr>


            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td>Result</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td>Result</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <input type="button" name="rank" value="Rank" onClick="rankPlayers(this.form)"/>
    </form>
```

I would like to iterate all fields and get the values at the press of the button, but I get undefined returned in the console log. I don't want to use IDs for each field as I want to do some column operations (add, multiply). My script for the first column looks like this:

```
            function rankPlayers(){
            var table=document.getElementById("table");
            for(var i=1; i<table.rows.length;i++){

                    console.log(table.rows[i].cells[0].value);
            }
        }
```

Any tips? Thanks

Comment: Why not iterate through the form elements and forget the table entirely?

Comment: Hi, because I need to do some linear operations (by column). Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to select the input from the cell:

```
// ------------------------------------v
console.log(table.rows[i].cells[0].firstChild.value);
```

---

If you could have siblings *(even whitespace)* around the inputs, then you can use the `.children` collection to target the correct element.

```
// ------------------------------------v
console.log(table.rows[i].cells[0].children[0].value);
```

---

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

You can change your loop to:

```
    var table=document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for(var i=1; i<table.length;i++){
        console.log(table[i].firstChild.value);
    }
```

This gets all `td` elements, loops them, and checks the `firstChild` value